# How to use getUserMedia on ios' browsers?

Tags: iphone, getusermedia

I can't use getUserMedia Api on ios, is there a method or a pollify to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

there isn't really a polyfill for getUserMedia since its just an API to the media devices (mic,camera) and IOS does not provide this API. Flash is sometimes used as an alternative, but the main IOS browsers do not support that either.

really the only option is to use an html input tag to upload a video, but that makes doing anything realtime impossible.